# When Inkscape opens file, objects are jumped over the page

Tags: inkscape, svg

When I save and then open a file with Inkscape, it loads with object dislocated. I can then fix the object's location (it jumps near correct location after even slight move), save, but after opening again the situation repeats. The original file is

https://github.com/psprint/zplugin/blob/master/doc/img/zplugin.svg

The effect of loading is below:

[image: Inkscape after opening file]

Comment: I clicked the github link and it looks like the issue is resolved. If that's the case, could you accept the answer? If it's not resolved, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

In XML code there is a translation command that moves the cube. You have to remove it.

[image: Inkscape after opening file]

You can also remove it selecting the cube's and setting its coordinates to x=0 and y=0

[image]

Comment: Tried both options and neither worked. Here is what I did manually: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/6775/xhwGTl.png

Comment: I used XML editor inside Inkscape (In Windows Shift+Ctrl+X). Then select "transform" and delete the value in the botton on dialog windows. This way I solved.

Comment: Doing what you wrote (via Inkscape XML editor) indeed instantly moves the object where it should be, however after saving and opening, it's still the same dislocated

Comment: @VolkerAmnu, I dont Know... I "saved as" in inkscape svg and pure svg. In both cases reopening the file, it's ok...

Comment: Maybe you could upload the fixed file somewhere? Maybe it will work for me too

Comment: Try http://we.tl/D7eBI949qz

Comment: Inkscape SVG still opens with the same issue. Pure SVG is fine, also when I create it myself. I've downloaded latest Inkscape for Mac.